# Problems running truffle

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, accounts, ropsten, truffle-contract

I am trying to follow a tutorial to deploy a smart contrat on Ropsten Testnet. I am in part 4. Deploy the contract to Ropsten test network:

https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-2-30b3d335aa1f

However, I am stuck at the point when creating a new account with truffle. The  line: 
truffle(default)> web3.personal.newAccount('verystrongpassword')

Should create a new account and give me the adress. But there is a 800A138F problem coming up.

I tried changing truffle.js to another name. The error doesn't come up but in the comand line what happens is that truffle opens up again like nothing has happened and in the folder there is a new web3.personal.newAccount('testpassword1234') file created.

Thanks in advance[image: Truffle]

Answer (score 0):

The functions you should use is this

```
web3.eth.personal.newAccount(password, [callback]);
```

This function takes a string as a password and returns a promise.
What a promise does is call the success function that you pass. Since you haven't passed any hence no success!

try this:

```
web3.eth.personal.newAccount('verystrongpassword')
.then(console.log);
```

which like you said will give you the address of the newly formed account.

If this didn't work, then:

Uninstall web3 and download the  older version. 1.0.0 is still under developoment, possibly a bug with windows.